# What's the difference between the keywords 'python' and 'python3' in command lines?

Tags: command-line, python, python3

I've seen two ways to open a python script using the commandline, these are:

```
python foo.py
```

and

```
python3 foo.py
```

I know, there are python2 etc, but what does `python` without a version do then and why did I see it recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of python simultaneously in your system. Currently, python versions 2.x.x and 3.x.x is installed in your system.

Python3 is installed alongside with python(2) because some apps may still have a dependency on older python(2).

So `python` will refer to version 2.x.x and `python3` will refer to version 3.

You can confirm the versions by:

```
python --version
python3 --version
```

Comment: i have installed version 3.7.8. i am not able to run python3.. how can i do that?

Comment: @SunilGarg, see https://superuser.com/questions/1762771/why-doesnt-the-winget-package-of-python-include-python3-exe

Comment: This answer is incorrect, `python` refers to "the first version of `python.exe` found on the PATH" (type `where python` to see all versions on the PATH and their order).  Also keep in mind that `py` can be used as of Python 3.7 (IIRC) to launch python which should read the shebang line in the script to choose the correct version (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57334281/936083) for more information).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple versions of Python can be installed alongside each other and which version of Python to use can be selected by the user. The command `python` starts the interactive Python 2.x interpreter and `python3` starts the interactive Python 3.x interpreter. For example:

```
C:\Windows\system32> python
Python 2.7.15rc1 
>>> 2+3
5
```

Many Python packages are packaged in separate versions for Python 2.x and Python 3.x and can also be installed alongside each other.

Python can run scripts interactively in a REPL. A read–eval–print loop (REPL), also termed an interactive top level or language shell, is a simple, interactive computer programming environment that takes single user inputs (i.e. single expressions), evaluates them, and returns the result to the user. Installing IPython allows the user to run blocks of code and scripts interactively in a more user-friendly way. Installing IPython 2.x alongside IPython 3.x gives the user the capability of interactively running blocks of both Python 2.x code and Python 3.x code.