# Why doesn't the winget package of python include python3.exe?

Tags: python3, winget

The [community-accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/936083) for including a shebang line for Python seems to be to use `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.  However, when I install Python 3 using the winget package (i.e. `winget install --id Python.Python.3.11`), and then attempt to run a script with the shebang (i.e. `py some_script_with_shebang.py`), I get an error:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings

> Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Through investigation, I found that I can install the `msstore` package to resolve this (`winget install --id 9NRWMJP3717K`, and `where python3` returns `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`).  However, I don't know why I need to install the `msstore` version (with the opaque ID), rather than the `winget` package (with the transparent ID).

Comment: NOT A SOLUTION, but when I discovered this, I simply found the folder where `python.exe` was and `mklink /h python3.exe "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin that might be the best solution unfortunately.  Apparently installing the `msstore` version on top of the other will not do what you want, as it just means now you have two versions, where `py -3` is one version and `python3` is another.  With different packages installed.

Comment: The reason I say that it's not a solution is because there is the risk of a disk check reporting "cross-linked" files - one of many holdovers from the DOS/FAT12 days. It's also not something for someone unfamiliar with the command line to do. Certainly, someone with familiarity with UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems (including Linux) would consider this an almost trivial workaround - but it's still going to be somewhat foreign to "old DOS hands" with little *IX exposure.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I wouldn't think twice about making a link, I'm surprised that it would be an issue.  Another alternative would just be making an alias.  In powershell, `md %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` > `notepad $profile` > paste `Set-Alias python3 path\to\python.exe`  Fair point though on it not being for someone unfamiliar with command line, my question *was* meant to be along the lines of "why doesn't `python3` work out of the box?".

Comment: The alias would only work _in_ powershell, and I suspect that the python loader that handles shebangs probably won't invoke powershell by default. Another alternative would be to create `PYTHON3.CMD` in the same folder as `PYTHON.EXE`, with content `@python %*`

Answer (score -2):

Could it be that you didn't re-open your command prompt after `winget install --id Python.Python.3.11`? In that case, the new `python` wouldn't have been on your `PATH` yet. Normally, winget does place Python on the PATH, but it only takes effect in new command prompt windows. This is discussed for example in https://winget.pro/winget-install-python/.

Comment: `python` is on the path, but there doesn't exist any `python3`, with the winget package.  I checked the install directory directly, this is not an "I forgot to restart my shell" problem.